# PowerShell - Why get-date -displayhint

Tags: powershell

Why, in PowerShell, is the format for date "get-date -displayhint" instead of "get-date -display"?  I understand that "get-date -display" works, however I don't understand the significance of the "hint".

Comment: Actually Ken, Matthew's question is a valid question. It could perhaps be phrased better. I'll explain in my answer.

Comment: @JoshEinstein, you're correct. :-) My mistake (misread the question - perhaps the phrasing, perhaps my fault). Deleting my comment so it doesn't lead others to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is PowerShell's ability to shortcut parameter names. Basically, the formal parameter name for that command is `-DisplayHint`. The reason that `-Display` works is because PowerShell will let you specify as little of the parameter name as necessary to disambiguate it from other parameters.

In fact, you could even specify just `-di` and it would work because there are no other parameters that begin with "Di" that would conflict. You couldn't, however, shorten it to `-d` because that would conflict with the `-Day` parameter and PowerShell wouldn't be able to determine which you meant to use.

Bonus tip: Many PowerShell commands specify short aliases for their parameter names. If you type `Get-Help <commandname> -Full` you can see the aliases that are offered for that command.

Comment: +1 with small comment. I think question was more on "why it's long when it could be short..." ;) IMO -Display as a parameter makes very little sense - Get-Date will "display" date in most (all?) use cases. Because PS team try to make parameters meaningful, thus things like -ComputerName or -Recurse. Luckily we can shorten (-R) or use parameter aliases (-CN) and still in scripts make command "readable" to human being w/o reading documentation for each cmdlet. I think it's very nice feature of PS. :>